# Fixed Document Page Rendered Event

Tags: c#, wpf

I am working on creating an extremely large report in C# / WPF. I have a FixedDocument that I add roughly 80 pages of PageContent. The pages being displayed are rather complex and I understand that rendering them all takes some time.

I'd like to show the user some sort of waiting dialog while the pages are being rendered. While I can create a wait dialog I have no idea on how to figure out when all the pages are loaded.

I've tried events on the fixed document and on each page but none of the events I've tried seems to fire at the end of the page rendering.

Is there an event I'm missing or is there a way to capture when the loading is completed.

Thanks!

Update with some loading code

This gets executed during the Loaded Event on the window that contains the FixedDocument. The InstrumentPageMaker generates a 1 - 4 page report based upon the size of the data.  I take the list of returned pages and add them to the fixed document. After this bit of code runs the program goes inert for about 30 seconds or so. I don't need all the events that are set up below. I was just trying all the ones that seemed appropriate.

```
        foreach (IInstrument instrument in sortedList)
        {
            List<PageContent> instrumentPages = InstrumentPageMaker.InstrumentPage(signalReport, instrument, dataStore, prevDataStore, ref pageNum);

            foreach(PageContent pc in instrumentPages)
            {
                pc.Loaded += pc_Loaded;
                pc.GetPageRootCompleted += pc_GetPageRootCompleted;
                pc.Initialized += pc_Initialized;
                pc.LayoutUpdated += pc_LayoutUpdated;
                pc.ManipulationCompleted += pc_ManipulationCompleted;


                signalReport.Pages.Add(pc);
            }
        }
```

Inside of each page are some rather large data grids with lots of bindings and converters (I'm looking to reduce the number of converters to increase speed).

Next I'm going to try and see if I can have datagrids inside of the pages event when finished rendering and from there pass an event further up.

Comment: Please show us your existing code.